# ns3 - How to modify only some files of an existing module?

Tags: networking, module, dependencies, simulation

how do I modify only some files of an existing module (i.e., aodv or dsr) and add the modified module in ns3? If I copy aodv structure and try to compile with aodv-mod, the compiler says there is a conflict between aodv-mod and aodv, because I didn't modify all file names, but only some.

Is there a clean way to extend a module and modify only some files or  are you forced to rename all files????

Comment: Its not the best practice. You can keep the original copy of aodv and then modify as you want. But if you want to add a new file (.cc/.h) or rename any existing file (.cc/.h) in aodv module, you should modify wscript file inside aodv directory.